# Change main keyboard layout in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings, input-source

I have two active keyboard layouts - US english and russian. I have russian as my primary system language and the option "allow different input language for different documents" is active. But when I open any app keyboard automatically switches to russian, while I want it to be english by default. Is there any way to change the default keyboard layout without changing system language?

Comment: What system are you on? On my Mac running Mavericks newly started apps just keep the keyboard layout that was selected before.

Answer (score 4):

When I tried enabling the setting (Input source options: Allow a different one for each document), new windows seemed to just use the current input source.

Anyway, you could try running `sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Setup\ Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Setup\ Assistant` and selecting US as the default input method. (You have to go through the steps of creating a new account, but you can delete it later.) It modifies at least `/var/root/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist`.

If that doesn't work, try running `sudo languagesetup` and selecting English, or `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist AppleLocale en_US` and restarting.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try the option **Use the same one in all documents** and with a keyboard shortcut you can easily switch between different input methods, for example, `Cmd + Space`.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to understand what you propose to do here, especially the part between the ""

Comment: With Monterey OS I do not have the option **Use the same one in all documents**